# Java - Infinite While Loop for counter

Tags: java, twitter, while-loop, infinite-loop, twitter4j

I am working in Java using Twitter4J to get a list of Twitter Followers. I am able to obtain and place the ID's into an array, but I only want to get 20 of them, and my while loop seems to go on infinitely to negative numbers.

I've tried debugging, printlns, and code refactoring.
I've also tried searches on stackoverflow but don't understand where I am going wrong?

```
public class Followers {

    public static void main(String[] a) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        long[] tempids = null;
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
        .setOAuthConsumerKey(key)
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret(key)
        .setOAuthAccessToken(key)
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(key);

        List ids = new ArrayList(); 

        long cursor = -1L; 
        Twitter twitter1 = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
        int count = 20;
        while(count>0)
        {
            try
            {               
                IDs temp    = twitter1.friendsFollowers().getFollowersIDs("cnn", cursor);
                System.out.println("TEMP: " + temp);
                cursor      = temp.getNextCursor();
                tempids = temp.getIDs();
                System.out.println("Long[] TempIDS: " + tempids.toString());
                System.out.println("count INSIDE: " + count); 
            } 

            catch (twitter4j.TwitterException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("twitter: failed");
                e.printStackTrace();
                //return null;
            }

            if(tempids != null) 
            {               
                    for (long id : tempids) 
                    {
                        ids.add(id);
                        System.out.println("Inside FOR LOOP adding IDS to list ");
                        System.out.println("followerID: " + ids.toString());
                        count--;
                        System.out.println("count AFTER DECREMENT: " + count); 
                        Thread.sleep(1000);                     
                    }
                }                  
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Your ids.size() is depended on `tempids[]` size. To get only 20 records, add 'break' condition in for loop too.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for this. Assume there is a problem and your code ends up in `catch (twitter4j.TwitterException e)` exception block repeatedly then it would be an infinite loop.

If `tempids` is null or empty then count will never be decremented

There seems to be another logical error too. Your are trying to get followers for 'cnn' 20 number of times(repeatedly with same data). This check for 20(while loop) should be moved to `for (long id : tempids)`. May be add a condition in the for loop to break once 20 results are extracted. I am not very aware of the Twitter lib so I could be wrong here! May be post some of the logs which are repeating and readers will get better insight into the problem.